# custom drupal ajax file upload

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to built an ajax function to save an upload file in Drupal 7.
Data are given to the function correctly, but the drupal file_save_upload only return 'null'

this is the files array to be processed:

```
[files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [image] => banner1.png
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [image] => image/png
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [image] => C:\Windows\Temp\php418.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [image] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [image] => 545281
                )

            [filename] => banner1.png
            [filesize] => 545281
        )
```

The file_save_upload looks like this:

```
  $destination_uri = file_build_uri('test/' . $user->uid);
  $ok = file_save_upload($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']['image'], array(), $destination_uri);
```

The file is not processed nor saved in DB.

What is missing here?

thank you.